# Resolving nuget package references

Tags: c#, nuget

I am writing an app which needs to load nuget packages dynamically (it uses Roslyn to scan for documentation, type information, etc).

I have a situation where I want to load the following package (info derived from a csproj file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>J4JSoftware.Logging</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>J4JSoftware.Logging</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The challenge is that my system's nuget cache does not have an assembly/DLL for a netstandard2.0 version of Serilog.Sinks.Console 3.1.1 (I don't think one exists online, either). All it has is one for netstandard1.3.

Yet the app that I'm scanning (i.e., the one with the requirement for Serilog.Sinks.Console 3.1.1 netstandard2.0) works perfectly fine. So the package requirement is being resolved, I presume, to the netstandard1.3 version...even though the project is netstandard2.0.

Questions:

- what's the best place for documentation on how nuget packages are resolved at runtime? Perhaps I could duplicate the resolving function in my scanning app.
- better yet, is there a library that handles the resolution automagically? Perhaps something that's part of nuget itself? I studied the nuget github project but didn't see such a thing, but I don't pretend to be a nuget expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like: `nuget update` or `nuget list` and interact from C# etc with the console. That way you are sort of getting a library like behavior but not baking your own code that may break across nuget versions.

NetStandard 1.3 is likely usable for Netstandard 2.0 as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) (but not the other way around).

Nuget versioning would declare that you want say Netstandard 2.0 and the package you are using might say it supports NetStandard 1.3+ (which includes Netstandard 2.0 implicitly). Nuget will select the highest one provided that suites your needs, in this case probably 1.3 as you indicated. Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution) on how nuget selects dependencies. I assume that this is the same way in how it determines runtime folders.

Comment: Reading the link you provided on how nuget selects dependencies, it seems like I might be able to figure out what specific DLLs are being resolved by parsing the obj/project.assets.json file. Thanx for the info!